# Does .Net do clever connection management like PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net, sqlconnection

During an ASP.NET page load I'm opening and closing multiple System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnections inside multiple controls contained in the page. I thought it would be a good idea instead to create a "pool" of connections and when opening a connection check to see if the connection string matches that of an open connection in the pool, and return that connection. I was expecting to see a difference in the page load times, but I haven't seen any change. I know that with PHP if you attempt to open a new connection with a connection string that has already been used in that page request it won't attempt to open a new connection and will return the existing open connection instead. Is this true with .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connection pooling is an essential feature of ADO.NET.

Read this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) or some of the other resources available on the net, like this [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/sjoseph/archive/2005/03/23/395601.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is basically how connection pooling works in ADO.NET.

When you call `Open()` on a Connection-instance, it doesn't necessarily open a connection. It fetches an open connection from the pool, matching the connection string. `Close()` releases the connection back into the pool.